# How can I draw this thick rounded corner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

How can I draw this specific shape in Photoshop? I tried 2 rectangles with border radius but I can't match it perfectly. It's probably easy, but Graphic Design is not my area.

[image: shape]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need one rectangle.

- Draw a rectangle and try to center the lines in the middle of the existing image.
- Use the **Properties Panel** to approximate the radius. You can adjust this in a moment if needed. (I've reduced opacity on the rectangle layer so I can see the underlying image as a guide).

[image]

- Change the shape properties to be a stroke with no fill and then play with the stroke width until it matches as close as possible.... It's kind of somewhere between 34 and 36px from what I can tell - I didn't zoom in and increment it by half pixels or minuscule amounts, so this image is ever so slightly off. You can use Arrow keys to nudge the rectangle into position better if needed. And if you find the radius isn't set correctly, you can tweak that as well.

[image]

- Grab the **Pen Tool** and **add** two anchor points where the rectangle should be broken. Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to click and delete the remaining portion of the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, instead of breaking up the rectangle with the pen tool, you could also [mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/layer-mask.html) the parts you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use border stroke in Blending Options.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! We want to be a quality reference, and therefore are looking for longer answers, that explain in-depth _how_ and _why_ something works. Could you [edit] your answer to expand on why you think this technique would work?